# CIR parameters calibration in R_Error in data[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions

Tags: r, rstudio, dimensions

I am working on data about bonds yields and I need to calibrate the parameters for a Cox-Ingersoll-Ross Model (CIR), but I can't find a solution to the error mentioned in the title. Here follows the code:

```
library(SMFI5)

R<-Germany_yields[,1]

tau<-Germany_yields[,2]

Ger_Y <-c(R,tau)

est.cir(Ger_Y, method = 'Hessian', days = 360 , significanceLevel = 0.95)

Error in data[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions.
```

How could I solve it?
Thank you in advance,
Andy.

Comment: You perhaps want `Ger_Y <- cbind(R,tau)`, or just `Ger_y <- Germany_yields[,1:2]`, otherwise it is just a long vector.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, have a nice day!